# How to auto-quit dropbox when a drive gets disconnected

Tags: mac, photos, dropbox

I store all my photos on a connected thunderbolt drive.  I use a symlink in dropbox folder to keep the photos backed up to dropbox. all good.

If I need to take my laptop with me, and I disconnect the external drive, then dropbox no longer sees the photos link, and proceeds to delete all the pics from dropbox.

I would like to auto disable/ close dropbox when this external drive is disconnected.

Any ideas how ?